# Is a system like __VIEWSTATE available in HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, html, input, viewstate

Do you know ASP.NET __VIEWSTATE?

I want this in HTML or PHP:

```
input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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> </input>
```

Comment: I cannot remember what `__VIEWSTATE` does but no in PHP that is just another `name` attribute like any other so if you are asking does PHP do anything special with that name the answer is NO

Comment: What `__VIEWSTATE` exactly does? Explain us because you tagged this question as PHP.

Comment: __VIEWSTATE

Hiding all source code prevents the input values from being changed and the page source to be displayed.

It comes with ASP.NET software. Applies to ASPX Pages.

Example: view-source:https://www.akbank.com/en-us/pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know Asp.NET __VIEWSTATE?

Yes. View state is a feature of ASP.NET which is used to store the state of a form across requests. The article [Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) will explain this in more detail.

View state does not "prevent the input values from being changed [or] the page source to be displayed". This is a misunderstanding on your part.

> Is a system like __VIEWSTATE available in html or php?

Not directly. HTML and PHP do not natively include any form handling features, so this functionality does not exist in them. However, some PHP frameworks may include similar features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In PHP it called CSRF token.

Comment: Not really. View state is more akin to a (client-side) session than a CSRF token. Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx